# GO command line problems after a "go get"

Tags: github, go, command-line, git-bash

So i just installed GO for the use of Primitive (here's the README.md) https://github.com/fogleman/primitive. What essentially is supposed to happen is that you give in an image and it recreates it using polygons. Here is an example of an image reconverted using Primitive https://codepen.io/DavQ/pen/wgVWzo

As it states

> Command-line Usage

```
go get -u github.com/fogleman/primitive

primitive -i input.png -o output.png -n 100
```

The first command runs fine and I checked if i had it with "go list ./..."
I am now within a test folder with just one image within the folder called "recursion.jpg" and run the command the docs provide

```
primitive -i recursion.jpg -o recursion.svg -n 100
```

The problem is with the command, I get the returned

```
-bash: primitive: command not found
```

obviously primitive is not a command the terminal recognizes, but as I just installed GO today for the sole use of Primitive, I am wondering what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

The README assumes that `$GOPATH/bin` is on your path.  Try running `$GOPATH/bin/primitive` or `$HOME/go/bin/primitive` if you did not set GOPATH.

Comment: if you are using go 1.8 with no GOPATH it will be `$HOME/go/bin/primitive`